# Authenticate app on server

Tags: http-basic-authentication

I did a website that is only allowed to people whose IP are whitelisted. 
Unfortunately for me, my client wants me to create an app. What I did, and it works since I've implemented a Basic Auth to allow my app to connect to the server.

But every time a user connects to the site without being whitelisted get an auth prompt, which I don't want to happen.

Is there any other way to allow my app to get server data (it's running on wordpress) than Basic Auth ?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you trying to make your app share a hostname with WordPress?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean @MichaelHampton

Comment: You do not separate your app from Wordpress? Why do you have them together?

Comment: Actually the app gets its content from the wordpress REST API of my website